# How to limit which images can be randomly displayed according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, image, random

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize for any mistakes. Also, I'm new to JavaScript! It's a beautiful coding language, but I'm having some troubles with it.

Now, to the question.

My goal is simple: I want to display randomized images on one part of my website. The catch is, since the website has a responsive design, there're two sets of images, one for each of the two screen-resolution sizes I'm working with.

So, in other words, what I want to achieve is: one set of images is randomized/displayed when using smaller screens, the other set is randomized/displayed when using bigger screens.

What I've done so far is:

1. Use a JavaScript code for randomizing the images. It goes as such:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var objetos = new Array();

    objetos[0] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[1] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[2] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[3] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[4] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[5] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[6] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[7] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[8] = "heregoesmypicture";
    objetos[9] = "heregoesmypicture";

    function aleatorio() {
       var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * objetos.length);
       document.getElementById("mi-imagenali").src = objetos[azar];
    }

window.onload=aleatorio;
});
    </script>
```

So, is there a way of limiting which images are displayed according to the size of the screen?
For example, to have images 0-4 show when the resolution is smaller and images 5-9 when it's larger.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, will you know `0-4` & `5-9`, the images range, in advance?

Comment: Yes, I already know the number of images and which images go in each range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS @media to hide the "extra" images for smaller screen sizes.  For example, the following CSS will hide images with the class "hideme" if the screen size is 600px wide or less.  You could use several @media paragraphs if needed.  Just add the class .hideme to the set of images you want to have hidden on smaller displays.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .hideme {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but I'm not sure how to go about adding the class .hideme to the images. Should I add it to the JavaScript code? Is that possible?

Comment: There are a few ways to go about it.  First, if the HTML for the page is scripted with something like PHP, you can programtically add the .hideme class to every other image.  It could be done with JQuery using something like this example: $( "img:odd" ).addClass('.hideme'); But that's just a guess based on the snippet you provided.